# Apache POI using Xml Beans 2.0.0

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xmlbeans

I'm currently customizing a third-party product where I would like to add a new functionality that requires Excel file reading. My first, and probably only, option is Apache POI.

The problem raised when I detected that this product has the Xml Beans already but a quite old 2.0.0 version from 2005 (jar named xbean.jar). The oldest Apache POI version in maven repositories shows that's compatible only with Xml Beans 2.3.0 or above: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/3.6

Considering changing the Xml Beans version embedded is absolutely not an option, does anyone know what POI version would be compatible with Xml Beans 2.0.0?

Thanks

Comment: Newer XMLBeans runtimes are backwards compatible with older-compiled classes. So, you should be fine to zap your ancient 2.0 jar and replace it with 2.3, or ideally 2.6. What happens when you try that?

Comment: @Gagravarr thank your this information, I didn't know it so I'll try. Still this JAR comes from a product with warranty so still is not the best solution because it'd remove the owner support.

Comment: I very much doubt that the current owners are providing any meaningful support for a version of xmlbeans that's that old...